# Is there a way to optionally add function in bundle?

Tags: javascript, webpack, module, bundler, rollup

Good day, My task is to create two different bundle one for CMS and another one for Product team and there are few function's which i want to be in bundle of CMS but not in the Product team.

I have a Class XYZ

```
Class XYZ {

constructor() {}

forCms() {}

forProduct() {}

}
```

and I want two different bundle:

For CMS(i need forCms function):

```
Class XYZ {

constructor() {}

forCms() {} //<--- notice methods

}
```

For Product(I need forProduct function):

```
Class XYZ {

constructor() {}

forProduct() {} //<--- notice methods

}
```

I searched a lot and I found Env. variable and i use them for some logic like:

```
function abc() {
        const env = process.env.NODE_ENV;
        switch (env) {
            case "cms":
                //some logic
                break;
            default:
               //some logic
                 });
        }
}
```

I have no idea, how can I achieve this? or Is there any different way beside's ENV. to accomplish this inside  bundler like Webpack or Rollup?

Any suggestion would be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to how to attach methods to prototype according to env variable, you could do something like:

```
export interface LayerManager {
    forCms: Function;
    forProduct: Function;
}

export class LayerManager {
    firstName: string = '';
    constructor(name: string) {}
}

// @ts-ignore
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "cms") {
    LayerManager.prototype.forCms = function() {}
} else {
    LayerManager.prototype.forProduct = function() {}
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgGUwE80BZTJTAczTgG8AoOZudaAYQFsBnALjgBiAVyTYYCCEgDcTFmygAFKBAAmQsf2GjxkmQF8GoSLDjYANpm7cCxMhWq1GLVgijcYAOUydg-d1GQqOABeOAByMJlnbEl-dRhoAApKHz8YAKQqAEp6WWdmGKRuCDNgADozCCpk72AsqPzmGAALBG4y%20S5uRPq8uAMDBgB6IbgAARhuAFoEKiRoYAYEdDhEsGVcKzLgJAA3Mo8AeQARAFEAfVOPADUQ4NCAImweB5ynFkISKHJKGigy9YQBIwIhgcqdHghVgiMQSJCrN79Bh6ODAMzcPDvZifOy-NAA5TA0Hg6BKVTxKHoGE6eE9ehIvRAA)

Comment: Thank you for your response and this works for me. Just one question is it the only way to do achieve this using ENV or there can be another way?

Comment: You mean other than amending prototype or without env variable? It is hard to suggest something without knowing the requirements and why is this needed at all..

Comment: This is the requirement of the project we are currently working on and we do not want to handle two different repository or branches for that. Solving this problem using prototype and env is one way.  I am just curious to know could there be any other way to handle this use case.