# TypeError: Duplicate declaration, Module build failed Error in Typescript Project

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, prototype, babeljs

Good Day,

I have code something like below

In A.ts file:

```
declare class LayerManager {
    //code
    constructor(factory: Factory);
    //code
}

let self: LayerManager;

function LayerManager(factory: Factory) {
   //code
   self = this;
   //code
}

export default LayerManager;
```

In B.ts file:

```
import LayerManager from '../layer-manager/index';

//Code

this.layer = new LayerManager(this.factory);  //<---In order to have construct Signature
```

I am using an approach Accepted on SO [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59420203/typescript-new-expression-whose-target-lacks-a-construct-signature-implicit)

The problem is i am getting an error of Module build fail(babel) continuously. Attaching Screenshot:

webpack:

```
{
                // Include ts, tsx, js, and jsx files.
                test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
                query: { compact: true }
},
```

Any suggestion would be helpful.

MINIMAL Reproduction added on [GITHUB](https://github.com/dollysingh3192/TS-Build-Fail-Reproduction)

[image]

Comment: Repro on codesandbox for example would be helpful.

Comment: Code on  https://github.com/dollysingh3192/TS-Build-Fail-Reproduction

Comment: `npm run type-check` in your repo runs without errors

Comment: My Apologies @AlekseyL. I forgot to add .babelrc file in the repo. I just add it . Can you help me why ```npm start``` is failing

Comment: Appears to be a known issue in babel https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/7943

Comment: Real question is why do you need this? Why normal class is not used?

Comment: Ohhh ohk. I have an open SO Link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64277110/is-there-a-way-to-optionally-add-function-in-bundle as we have a diffrent requirement in our Project and I couldn't found any workaround. Using prototype approach I am just doing ``` if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "cms") {
    LayerManager.prototype.forCms = function() {}
}```.

Comment: Still don't get how is it related to defining class as function 

Comment: Till now I didn't get any solution of the bounty problem where i can dynamically inject function in bundle using two different ENV. variable's "cms"/"product". That's why using old approach of Prototyping  ``` if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "cms") { LayerManager.prototype.forCms = function() {} }``` i am injecting function in bundle, as  normal class don't allow me to do that. Any suggestion on that?

Comment: You can amend class prototype the same way https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgGUwE80BZTJTAczTgG8AoOZudaAYQFsBnALjgpEA3AwC+DUJFhxsAG0zduBYmQrVajFqwRRuMAHKZOwfnqjIqcALxwA5LZFbsEJGYCu2GNAAUlY6ZhzJCoASnomLRZnVwhZYAA6WQgqXyNgEMdI5hgACwRueLYoLm5vDIjmcXEGAHoauAABGG4AWgQqJGhgBgR0OG8wKAhcRXjgJAA3eP0AeQARAFEAfQX9ADVrKxsAImwebbDNFkISKHJKGih4wYgvGCIwBKKS61Y3JE8EFzL6cS06xrNNodLpiODAWTcPC9fo3EYFcZTWaLFbrTY2WwAE2AEwhEDAxhQtkOFWUp3O6iuNzuDyeHB4r3Q70+3xJWWY0W4sQSSRSWJxxNJVSAA

Comment: @AlekseyL.  This works. Thanks for your time and SO is awesome as always and you  mind adding your answer in the original question as well. I will be happy to accept.